# How to pass the TCP connection variables in the main class to another JFrame classes?

Tags: java, swing, sockets, user-interface

i have a main class with a method that starts a connection with server.
in the JFrame class i have a button signup that when pressed it will retrieve the user input and sends it to the server.
my problem is that the connection to the server is not working because of a mistake with passing the variables from the main method.
i tried declaring in the JFrame class the variables for the connection and assigning them in the constructor to the main class variables but this also did not work.

main class:

```
     public class TCPClient  {
    Socket clientSocket;
DataOutputStream outToServer;
BufferedReader inFromServer;
String test;


public void start() throws Exception{
   clientSocket= new Socket("localhost", 6789); 
   outToServer=  new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream()); 
   inFromServer= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())); 
   test="abc";

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TCPClient c=new TCPClient ();

    c.start();
      NewJFrame j=new NewJFrame();
      j.setVisible(true);
  }}
```

JFrame class:

```
    public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  JTextField username = new JTextField();
  JTextField name = new JTextField();
JTextField Email = new JTextField();
 JTextField Address = new JTextField();
    JTextField password = new JPasswordField();


    BufferedReader inFromUser;
    Socket clientSocket;
    DataOutputStream outToServer;
    BufferedReader inFromServer;
    String test;


public NewJFrame() throws Exception {
     TCPClient c=new TCPClient();
     c.start();
    inFromServer=c.inFromServer;
    clientSocket=c.clientSocket;
    outToServer=c.outToServer;
    inFromServer=c.inFromServer;
    test=c.test;
    initComponents();
       }
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
System.out.print(test);
    Object[] message = {
"Full Name:", name,
"Email:", Email,
"Address:", Address,
"Username:", username,
"Password:", password
 };

   int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message,"Sign in",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

    try{

    System.out.print(test);

    outToServer.writeBytes("signup"+ '\n');
    outToServer.writeBytes(name.getText() + '\n'); 
    outToServer.writeBytes(Email.getText() + '\n'); 
    outToServer.writeBytes(Address.getText() + '\n'); 
    outToServer.writeBytes(username.getText() + '\n');
    outToServer.writeBytes(password.getText() + '\n');

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, inFromServer.readLine());

    clientSocket.close(); 

   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {

    }
```

Comment: Please expand on "Did not work". What happened?  What did you expect to happen?

Comment: the server is not receiving from the client "outToServer.writeBytes()", but when i initialize the connection in the jButton1ActionPerformed method and not in the main class, it works

Comment: Not sure if this will help this problem, but catching Exceptions and doing nothing is never a good idea.  Add at least a println to make sure you don't have an exception occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the question:

> a mistake with passing the variables from the main method

Your main method doesn't pass anything to the JFrame constructor. Instead, the constructor creates a new TCP client and starts it again. The constructor should be defined as

```
public NewJFrame(TCPClient tcpClient) {
    ...
```

And the main method should pass the TCPClient, that it has already created and started, to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Since you close the socket connection in your `actionPerformed` method, I would suggest doing the opening of the connection there as well.

Reasoning:

1. If you open the connection outside the method you might not ever close it.
2. If this action is ever called twice it will fail.  I realize by design this should only be called once, but you have to be prepared for someone to change the code after you.
3. It works and your didn't post enough info in the question to tell why doesn't work otherwise.

Comment: thank you for your comment i will take that into consideration. probably i wont close it in this method.